# How set VS Code to show Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, alpine.js

My valid alpine.js code is sometimes shown as error/red in vscode. Does anyone know how to fix this in vscode?
[image]

Comment: Is the issue the `@` character?

Comment: That's true. But it is valid alpine.js code. So maybe in the settings of VS Code there is a way to approve this (among other alpine syntaxes) so that it is not colored red in my code.

Comment: I don't get this error tbh, but I can recommend an Alpine.js plugin for vscode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.alpine-js-intellisense

Comment: I installed the plugin, but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Do you still get this error? I cannot reproduce this in vscode. What plugins are you using?